# Reformat List of Table Columns by Header

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure there's something obvious I'm missing, so any help is appreciated. I'm working with a Data Table in a Table Format. I have a few headers I'd like to reformat in a General number format. I'm unsure if the data when it's dropped in will remain the same so I figure I'd like to work off of names rather than the column numbers or letters. This is part of a bigger project, but this is the first steps so the rest is irrelevant for now.

When I run this I get the error

> Run-Time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method

on the `.Union` block.

```
Dim Table As Excel.ListObject
Dim SortColIndex As Long
Dim SortCol As Range

Private Sub DefineVars()

Set Table = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("_Data")
SortColIndex = Table.ListColumns("Bill to Account Number").Index
Set SortCol = Table.ListColumns(SortColIndex).Range

End Sub

Sub Fedex()

Call DefineVars

With Table
    .Union(.ListColumns("Bill to Account Number").DataBodyRange, _
    .ListColumns("Net Charge Amount").DataBodyRange, _
    .ListColumns("Tracking ID Charge Amount").DataBodyRange, _
    .ListColumns("Tracking ID Charge Amount9").DataBodyRange, _
    .ListColumns("Tracking ID Charge Amount11").DataBodyRange).Select
End With
With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "General"
End With

With Table
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=SortCol, _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlDescending
    With .Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, I've added explanation inside the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Fedex()

Dim Tbl As ListObject
Dim TblRng As Range

'Call DefineVars

' set the ListObject (assuming you have 1 table in your worksheet)
Set Tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects(1) ' rename according to your sheet's name

With Tbl
    ' set the Range inside the ListObject (don't use Select)
    Set TblRng = Application.Union(.ListColumns("Bill to Account Number").DataBodyRange, _
                .ListColumns("Net Charge Amount").DataBodyRange, _
                .ListColumns("Tracking ID Charge Amount").DataBodyRange, _
                .ListColumns("Tracking ID Charge Amount9").DataBodyRange, _
                .ListColumns("Tracking ID Charge Amount11").DataBodyRange)
End With
With TblRng
    .NumberFormat = "General"
End With

' rest of your code ...

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Shai Rado, I added some things into my original code to show the variables I had declared but forgotten to keep in the question.

Comment: @MarkS. you can just swap `Tbl` with `Table` and the code should work

Comment: no worries, I got that all sorted. I'm not *that* much of noobie.